# Naming-convention [view].mobile.cshtml only when in portrait?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

ASP .NET MVC 4 has a nice `naming convention` which serves `[view].mobile.cshtml` pages (if they exist) when browsing from a smartphone.

Is there a way to take advantage of this feature only when the smartphone is in `portrait` mode, and let the standard pages `[view].cshtml` be served when the smartphone is in `landscape` mode ?

Comment: I find it a strange decision to serve mobile based on whether the mobile is in portrait or landscape. For example, an iPhone6+ in portrait probably has more width than a lot of other phones in landscape

Comment: Portrait display usually needs more adjustments than the portrait display which is basically just a PC in a smaller screen while keeping more or less the same ratio. The idea is to deal with landscape with css and media modifications, and to deal with portrait using a dedicated view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mobile templates are only there to serve page content specific to mobile devices. No determination is made about the viewport of the device: only whether or not it's "mobile". This mostly a mainstay from a simpler time, when you could actually have a "mobile" site. Nowadays, the definition of "mobile" is so convoluted that it hardly has any meaning. Is a laptop "mobile"? Everyone would consider a tablet "mobile", but some have higher resolutions than some desktop computers.

If you're concerned about viewport size or orientation, then you should actually be using CSS media queries (responsive design), rather than mobile templates. Only use the mobile templates if you need to actually deliver different content to mobile devices (adaptive design).

Comment: I see the ideal would be to serve a different content (different layout) when we switch from Landscape to Portrait, rather that from PC to Mobile since Mobile and PCs are getting closer in screen resolution. In this aspect, CSS Media queries are somehow limited.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding. Screen orientation should not be a factor in what content is returned by the server. At the very least what do you think should occur if the user switches the orientation after loading the page? No request will be issued to the server for new content based on the current orientation. This is why media queries exist. If you really want to customize what content is display per orientation, then you simply need to send everything for both and use media queries to show/hide elements.

Comment: Ok I see. So the server just sends everything to the browser, and use Media queries to show/hide elements to achieve either the portrait or the landscape layout, even if their are quite different in their design. Eg a picture displayed on the top left for a landscape layout, and displayed in the bottom center for a portrait layout.